# My if-else-then logic in onClick does not result in any DOM change

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I just wanna create a function that returns `"login"` if I clicked on login `div` and the same with signup.

But my code always returns the `else` condition even when clicking on the `div` which is supposed to change the parameter value.

```js
const Join = () => {
  const form = (state) =>  {
    if (state == 'login') {
      return "login"
    } else if (state == 'logup') {
      return "logup"
    } else {
      return "external-box"
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='Join'>
      <div className={form()}> 
        <div className='signin-section' onClick={() => form('login')}>Sign in</div>
        <div className='signup-section'onClick={() => form('logup')}>Sign up</div>
        <div className='loginfrm'>login</div>
        <div className='logupfrm'>logup</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Join />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id=root></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to catch the value returned by the onClick callback. You can use `useState` to declare an initial state and track changes to describe which section should be displayed. Then in the JSX part, you can use this state variable to check whether one form or the other needs to be displayed.

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-breeze-8bu4n4?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [visibleSection, setVisibleSection] = useState("login");

  const form = () => {
    if (visibleSection === "login") {
      return "login";
    } else if (visibleSection === "signup") {
      return "signup";
    } else {
      return "external-box";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Join">
      <div className={form()}>
        <div
          className="signin-section"
          onClick={() => setVisibleSection("login")}
        >
          Sign in
        </div>
        <div
          className="signup-section"
          onClick={() => setVisibleSection("signup")}
        >
          Sign up
        </div>
        <br />
        {visibleSection === "login" && <div className="loginfrm">login</div>}
        {visibleSection === "signup" && <div className="logupfrm">signup</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not return else part.

```js
const Join = () => {
  const form = (state) =>  {
    if (state == 'login') {
      return "login"
    } else if (state == 'logup') {
      return "logup"
    } else {
      return "external-box"
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='Join'>
      <div className={form()}> 
        <div className='signin-section' onClick={() => alert(form('login'))}>Sign in</div>
        <div className='signup-section'onClick={() => alert(form('logup'))}>Sign up</div>
        <div className='loginfrm'>login</div>
        <div className='logupfrm'>logup</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Join />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id=root></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```